# Postfix/Dovecot presenting default SSL certificate from Apache to Thunderbird client

Tags: linux, email, postfix, apache-2.4, dovecot

I've been struggling with this issue for some time now.

I want thunderbird to get the certificate for mail.******.cl, but it always seem to get ******.cl.

So I've done a couple of tests, and realized it was getting the default certificate Apache was delivering, not the one Postfix/Dovecot would deliver. Disabling Apache2 solves the issue. Dissiting my sites one by one makes it to deliver the certificate for the next site in order. Making a site for mail.****.cl makes it deliver it's certificate, but thunderbird then says it's for the wrong site ,it always try to get the certificate for ****.cl, even when it autodetected mail.*****.cl for sending and receiving.

I've tried another mail clients with similar results. Disabling Apache COMPLETELY solves the issue, and it delivers the correct certificate.

My Apache SNI's seems to be configured correctly. My DNS seems fine, there is an A record pointing to the machine's IP for mail.*****.cl, an A record for *****.cl, which works correctly. Also a reverse DNS for mail pointing to my droplet's IP

Maybe the only solution is just creating a separate droplet for Apache, and leaving this one for mail?

I've tried a lot to get this thing working, but can't seem to get the result I want.

[Thunderbird getting wrong certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnXpj.png)

Edit: I've tried creating a vhost for mi mail.domain.cl, that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mail.domain.cl

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/domain/.certs/mail.domain.cl/mail.domain.cl.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/domain/.certs/mail.domain.cl/mail.domain.cl.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/domain/.certs/mail.domain.cl/mail.domain.cl.fullchain.crt

    Redirect 403 /
    ErrorDocument 403 "Acceso Denegado"
</VirtualHost>
```

But Thunderbird is still trying to get the certificate (at the moment of adding the email account) from my root domain, which is really awkward. Mail still works fine, but will be an issue when I try to create new accounts for my clients.

It should try to fetch the certificate from mail.domain.cl, not from domain.cl.
Furthermore, I found this on apache logs:

```
54.37.79.75 - - [29/Jan/2024:01:11:21 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 286 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
205.210.31.237 - - [29/Jan/2024:01:16:41 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 483 "-" "-"
205.210.31.237 - - [29/Jan/2024:01:16:42 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 483 "-" "-"
176.97.210.231 - - [29/Jan/2024:01:52:14 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 230 "-" "-"
45.142.182.85 - - [29/Jan/2024:01:52:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 230 "-" "-"
71.6.232.28 - - [29/Jan/2024:01:59:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 230 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36"
192.241.210.35 - - [29/Jan/2024:02:05:33 +0000] "MGLNDD_165.232.153.205_80\n" 400 483 "-" "-"
207.248.203.238 - - [29/Jan/2024:02:15:37 +0000] "GET /.well-known/autoconfig/mail/config-v1.1.xml?emailaddress=jairo%40domain.cl HTTP/1.1" 404 491 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:115.0) Gecko/20100101 Thunderbird/115.7.0"
207.248.203.238 - - [29/Jan/2024:02:16:50 +0000] "GET /.well-known/autoconfig/mail/config-v1.1.xml?emailaddress=jairo%40domain.cl HTTP/1.1" 404 491 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:115.0) Gecko/20100101 Thunderbird/115.7.0"
207.248.203.238 - - [29/Jan/2024:02:17:49 +0000] "GET /.well-known/autoconfig/mail/config-v1.1.xml?emailaddress=jairo%40domain.cl HTTP/1.1" 404 491 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:115.0) Gecko/20100101 Thunderbird/115.7.0"
```

Which indicates me it tries to fetch an autoconfig xml, which is not finding. Idk if that's related to the issue.

My DNS records look like this:
[DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL2e0.png)

Edit2:

My postfix main.cf:

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 3.6 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 3.6



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/postfix.fullchain.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/postfix.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.domain.cl
mydomain = domain.cl
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain, ubuntu-intelsoft, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination

mua_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
mua_helo_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
mua_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject

# Milter configuration for OpenDKIM
milter_protocol = 6
milter_default_action = accept
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

And my dovecot conf.d/10-ssl.conf:

```
##
## SSL settings
##

# SSL/TLS support: yes, no, required. <doc/wiki/SSL.txt>
ssl = yes

# PEM encoded X.509 SSL/TLS certificate and private key. They're opened before
# dropping root privileges, so keep the key file unreadable by anyone but
# root. Included doc/mkcert.sh can be used to easily generate self-signed
# certificate, just make sure to update the domains in dovecot-openssl.cnf
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/postfix.fullchain.crt
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/postfix.key

# If key file is password protected, give the password here. Alternatively
# give it when starting dovecot with -p parameter. Since this file is often
# world-readable, you may want to place this setting instead to a different
# root owned 0600 file by using ssl_key_password = <path.
#ssl_key_password =

# PEM encoded trusted certificate authority. Set this only if you intend to use
# ssl_verify_client_cert=yes. The file should contain the CA certificate(s)
# followed by the matching CRL(s). (e.g. ssl_ca = </etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem)
#ssl_ca =

# Require that CRL check succeeds for client certificates.
#ssl_require_crl = yes

# Directory and/or file for trusted SSL CA certificates. These are used only
# when Dovecot needs to act as an SSL client (e.g. imapc backend or
# submission service). The directory is usually /etc/ssl/certs in
# Debian-based systems and the file is /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem in
# RedHat-based systems. Note that ssl_client_ca_file isn't recommended with
# large CA bundles, because it leads to excessive memory usage.
#ssl_client_ca_dir =
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
#ssl_client_ca_file =

# Require valid cert when connecting to a remote server
#ssl_client_require_valid_cert = yes

# Request client to send a certificate. If you also want to require it, set
# auth_ssl_require_client_cert=yes in auth section.
#ssl_verify_client_cert = no

# Which field from certificate to use for username. commonName and
# x500UniqueIdentifier are the usual choices. You'll also need to set
# auth_ssl_username_from_cert=yes.
#ssl_cert_username_field = commonName

# SSL DH parameters
# Generate new params with `openssl dhparam -out /etc/dovecot/dh.pem 4096`
# Or migrate from old ssl-parameters.dat file with the command dovecot
# gives on startup when ssl_dh is unset.
ssl_dh = </usr/share/dovecot/dh.pem

# Minimum SSL protocol version to use. Potentially recognized values are SSLv3,
# TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3, depending on the OpenSSL version used.
#
# Dovecot also recognizes values ANY and LATEST. ANY matches with any protocol
# version, and LATEST matches with the latest version supported by library.
#ssl_min_protocol = TLSv1.2

# SSL ciphers to use, the default is:
#ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!kRSA:!SRP:!kDHd:!DSS:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!ADH:!LOW@STRENGTH
# To disable non-EC DH, use:
#ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!DH:!kRSA:!SRP:!kDHd:!DSS:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!ADH:!LOW@STRENGTH

# Colon separated list of elliptic curves to use. Empty value (the default)
# means use the defaults from the SSL library. P-521:P-384:P-256 would be an
# example of a valid value.
#ssl_curve_list =

# Prefer the server's order of ciphers over client's.
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = no

# SSL crypto device to use, for valid values run "openssl engine"
#ssl_crypto_device =

# SSL extra options. Currently supported options are:
#   compression - Enable compression.
#   no_ticket - Disable SSL session tickets.
#ssl_options =
```

As I mentioned earlier, disabling apache gives Thunderbird, or any mail client the correct certificate, no errors. Enabling it shows an expired cert from my domain.cl.

I'm thinking rn to just create another droplet, and disabling apache for good on my mail.domain.cl IP.

Any better ideas on how to deliver the correct cert?

Edit 3: doveconf -n output:

```
# 2.3.16 (7e2e900c1a): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.16 (09c29328)
# OS: Linux 5.15.0-92-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
# Hostname: ubuntu-intelsoft
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = " imap"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/postfix.fullchain.crt
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Comment: Show us your config. Tell us what services you have a problem with. How is Thunderbird communicating with your mailserver?

Comment: Hi, it seems apache is intercepting something (autoconfig?) from thunderbird, and not getting it from .well-known/autoconfig/mail/config-v1.1.xml

I'm dealing with postfix and dovecot, which works just fine while apache is disabled, retrieving the correct SSL certificate.

While apache is enabled it delivers the certificate for the DN (intelsoft.cl actually) which is expired (for test purposes rn)

It should deliver the certificate in the postfix/dovecot config, which is valid.

I'm now trying to add debug options to thunderbird so I can have a better glimpse of what's going on.

Comment: Does this happen when you attempt to add account to thunderbird? If so it's probably autodiscovery; simply add a vhost with correct certificate and name to Apache.

Comment: It still tries to obtain the certificate for intelsoft.cl, instead the one from mail.intelsoft.cl. I'm guessing A record + redirection?

My sites enabled looks like this:

010-peludos.conf  015-peludos-ssl.conf  020-intelsoft.conf  025-intelsoft-ssl.conf  035-mail.intelsoft-ssl.conf

My vhost:
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mail.intelsoft.cl

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /correct/crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /correct/key
    SSLCertificateChainFile  /correct/fullchain/cert

    Redirect 403 /
    ErrorDocument 403 "Acceso Denegado"
</VirtualHost>

Comment: [Edit] your question to include new information. And explain what you're attempting to do.

Comment: Okay! just edited.

Comment: I don't understand what your are trying to do? Do you want to use IMAPS or SMTPS from Thunderbird? How does your postfix and dovecot configuration looks like?

Comment: I edited the answer with those config files. I'm using IMAP with SSL/TLS. I'm trying to get the mail clients to retrieve the correct certs from my server, but they always retrieve my domain.cl cert instead of the mail.domain.cl cert!

Comment: Why do you want to include apache using imap? Apache is a webserver for http and https

Comment: I don't want to include it, but it's kinda conflicting with the certificates my email server is delivering. If I disable apache, the problem goes away, and the correct certificate gets delivered by my mail server, so that's why I include apache in the issue.

Comment: Please show the running dovecot config with `doveconf -n`. And can you leave apache disabled or do you need apache also?

Comment: To disable apache I should move my web server to another droplet / ip. I could do that, but will mean costs. Wanted to try without using 2 servers. I edit my message for doveconf -n output

Comment: Please check your certificate with `openssl x509 -noout -text -in /etc/ssl/certs/postfix.fullchain.crt | grep -E "DNS|Subject Alternative Name" `

Comment: X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:mail.intelsoft.cl

it's the correct certificate for sure

The one that it's delivering while apache is running says this:
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:intelsoft.cl

Answer (score 0):

It seems Thunderbird attempts autodiscovery, which gives it the wrong certificate.

Create a vhost in Apache for that subdomain, with the same certificate as used for dovecot.

Comment: already done that, it's in the first edit, thunderbird still tries to get it from domain.cl. Also tried disabling every vhost and only enabling the mail.domain.cl one. In that case, thunderbird got the correct certificate, shown the correct subdomain (mail.domain.cl), but shown a warning that domain is incorrect, probably because it redirected to mail.domain.cl while trying to get it from domain.cl. A solution I see here is issuing a good certificate for domain.cl (I'm issuing an expired one for testing purposes) but still won't get a fullchain, and I want the mail.domain.cl certificate.

Comment: Get a valid domain for `domain.cl` then.

Answer (score -1):

Check for which domain `/etc/ssl/certs/postfix.fullchain.crt` is issued

Also make sure imaps and pop3s are enabled (in `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`)

```
protocols = imaps pop3s
```

Comment: removing < breaks login
and adding imaps to protocols makes dovecot service unable to restart

Comment: also, I changed it to use 993, but I still have that cert warning and getting domain.cl cert instead of mail.domain.cl cert

Comment: Sorry the protocols should be checked in the main dovecot.conf `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`